# Vistas materializadas - Refresh cada diez minutos

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, vistas-materializadas

¿Cómo hago para que mi vista materializada se refresque (actualice) cada 10 minutos? He intentado con este código, pero no funciona

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW practica
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH COMPLETE START WITH SYSDATE NEXT (SYSDATE + 0.1/24)
AS 
SELECT * FROM tablavistaejemplo;
```

(Solo hago esto como practica y para ver resultados, sé que no se debe hacer nunca así)

Estoy usando PL/SQL - Oracle 11g - Sql developer

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar el procedure DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH()

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('practica', 'C');
END;
```

Esto va a refrescar la vista materializada usando el metodo refresh 'COMPLETE', que se updetea cuando se ejecuta la query que la define. El parametro C indica que se debe refrescar cuanto antes.

Podes agendar que se 'refresque' automaticamente creando un job que use el paquete DBMS_SCHEDULER, asi:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
    job_name => 'refresh_practica',
    job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    job_action => 'BEGIN DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH(''practica'', ''C''); END;',
    repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=10',
    start_date => SYSTIMESTAMP,
    enabled => TRUE
  );
END;
```